# Remix: Add to "Deployed Contracts" list programmatically (!) via JavaScript

Tags: remix

In Remix, when deploying contracts manually in the "Deploy and run transactions" tab, they show up in the "Deployed Contracts" list.

Remix also comes with the deploy_web3.js script that demonstrates how to deploy in an automated fashion. However, the script merely prints the deployed contract's address and it has to be added manually to the UI's list of deployed contracts using the "At Address" button. This is cumbersome when deploying multiple contracts in one go.

Is there a way to add the newly deployed contract to the list using JavaScript?